# HTML5 attribute alternate syntax for mobile site compatible with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, syntax, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile site using JQM (jQueryMobile) and HTML5 and I wanted to know (going forward with HTML5) what is the correct syntax?

What I'm currently doing

```
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="required" placeholder="Phone Number*" />
```

HTML5 version (no double quotes needed)

```
<input type=tel name=phone id=phone required placeholder="Phone Number*" />
```

My issue is if I use jQuery for the form validation I need to add the class="required", but if I use HTML5 form validation I can just add the required attribute. I thought I could use in HTML5 and keep the current syntax `required="required"` to enable required and `required=""` to disable required, but that's not the case. if the word required is in the element tag HTML5 requires it.

If I switch to HTML5 syntax are there any issues in using jQuery/JQM functionality? (As the HTML5 validation is noce but I would still like to use jQuery as a "Just in case" backup)

NOTE: I'm also using server side validation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about `progressive enhancement`, try to stick with syntax looking like html4.1.
It will be handled well by older browsers and feature-phones.

jQuery Mobile does its magic even if your html is not html5

Comment: understandable, just wanted to take the best approach. Also was thinking that using HTML5 would help keep the file size smaller if I needed to add additional jQuery validation. Note, this will only run on smartphones as the main site uses a different framework altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend relying on the jQuery validation, and progressively enhancing with HTML5 validation when possible.  Detect when HTML5 validation is available through Modernizr, or with the following snippet (borrowed from [Mark Pilgram's diveintohtml5.ep.io](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/everything.html#novalidate)):

```
function can_html5_validate() {
    return 'noValidate' in document.createElement('form');
}
```

If it is available, use the HTML5 validation, otherwise, fall back to jQuery.  I used this method and did not notice any conflicts with jQuery's validation plug-in.

Comment: I do like the jQuery Validation plug-in but I did notice this other plug-in that I liked: http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html  any thoughts?

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome!  I haven't seen it before, but if it works as well as it claims to, I would definitely go with that.